# "Has utilizado" versus "has sido utilizado"

Tags: tiempos-pasados

I want to form sentences with "has utilizado mi bicicleta" and "has sido utilizado mi bicicleta". Is there a special differences between them?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the verb you are conjugating is "utilizar", with a zeta, so the two conjugations are "has utilizado" and "has sido utilizado".
Second, if we add the subjects, we get "tú has utilizado" (you have used) and "tú has sido utilizado" (you have been used). The second is passive voice, the subject being the one who is used.
Therefore, "has sido utilizado mi bicleta" is incorrect. If you want to say that the bike has been used by someone, it should be "la bicicleta HA sido utilizada", using third person.